# SceneView get Anchors in same order as when they where created

Tags: geospatial, arcore, sceneview

I am using SceneView for accessing the ARCore Geospatial API.

When I create several EarthAnchors with

```
val earth = arSceneView.session?.earth ?: return
if (earth.trackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
    // Place the earth anchor at the same altitude as that of the camera to make it easier to view.
    val altitude = earth.cameraGeospatialPose.altitudeMeters - 1
    val rotation = Rotation(0f, 0f, 0f)
    // Put the anchor somewhere around the user.
    val latitude = earth.cameraGeospatialPose.latitude + 0.0004
    val longitude = earth.cameraGeospatialPose.longitude + 0.0004
    earthAnchor = earth.createAnchor(latitude, longitude, altitude, rotation)
}
// Attach the anchor to the arModelNode.
arModelNode.anchor = earthAnchor
```

everything works fine. But when I call [`ARSession getAllAnchors`](https://sceneview.github.io/api/sceneview-android/arsceneview/io.github.sceneview.ar.arcore/-a-r-session/index.html#-30554050%2FFunctions%2F1238612933) the order has changed.

Instead of the order I had while creating them (1, 2, 3), I get (1, 3, 2).
Is there any way I can get the anchors in the same order I created them?